# How to get definitive url from href value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-routing

I have some links with various hrefs and want to get definitive url for this value, like:

```
http://localhost/   -> http://localhost/
localhost           -> http://mysite.example/localhost
firstpage           -> http://mysite.example/firstpage
/anotherpage        -> http://mysite.example/anotherpage
#anchor1            -> http://mysite.example/currentpage#anchor1
/#anchor2           -> http://mysite.example/#anchor2
```

BTW I don't want code for click handling. I can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("a:first").prop("href")` will give you the full URL of your first anchor tag as opposed to `$("a:first").attr("href")` which will give you the text in the href attribute.

Comment: Sure: `element.href` will return the full URL and `element.getAttribute("href")` will return the attribute value as it was defined.